# With MSMQ how do I avoid Insufficient Resources when importing a large number of messages into a queue?

Tags: msmq

### What?

I have a private MSMQ transactional queue that I need to export all (600k) messages, purge then import the messages back into the queue. When importing these messages I'm currently using a single transaction and getting an insufficient resources error. I can switch to use multiple transactions but I need a way to work out how many messages I can process in a single transaction, any ideas?

### Why ?

If we don't periodically perform this operation the .mq files become bloated and fragmented. If there is another way to fix this problem let me know.

Comment: How many messages normally sit in a queue? Clearing out the queue by consuming all the messages normally allows that activity to happen on it's own.

Comment: It varies throughout the month but it can get up to 600k messages. So far we have not found another way to defrag/shrink the .mq files other than emptying the queue and then putting the messages back.

Comment: Yeah. There isn't really. The way MSMQ is designed to work, the queues should be empty more often than not. It sounds like you're using MSMQ more for storage than data in transit. I'd consider thinking about moving that data out MSMQ at some point in the future if you can.

Comment: Wait, there are 600,000 messages in ONE transaction?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with MQ files when we got 7500 MQ-files with the total size about 30 gigabytes.
The solution is very easy.
You should purge Transaction dead-letter messages on this machine and after that you should restart MSMQ service.
When this service starts it runs defragmentation procedure. It compacts used space and removes unused MQ files.